# django-mongodb-engine issues no queries under wsgi environment

Tags: python, django, mongodb

This is one that's really making me tear my hair out. I have a Django environment that's hooked to a mongodb replica set. At home, on my local test box I am able to set up the connection to the remote host and get data back from the database just fine. If I launch django via manage.py runserver on the actual host box, I also get data just fine.

The actual environment of the site is running with wsgi under an apache server. Once I launch the django site through apache, I stop receiving any data from the DB (even more, I've determined that there aren't any queries being fired *at all* from Django).

With this problem there are no errors, no debug statements, no messages nor any traces of anything wrong other than "It just doesn't work." After days of testing I can verify that:

- The mongodb *is* getting connected and authenticated properly from the Django site
- Since django-mongodb-engine uses PyMongo as its base I am able to (both in a python shell and in a "test mode" on the live site, access the mongodb and receive data).
- It seems the problem must lie within django-mongodb-engine somewhere, but I'm baffled as to how to proceed any further.

For some data, and I can provide whatever is needed, here's at least a pip freeze of the django environment if it helps at all...

```
Django==1.5.11
Pillow==2.2.1
Unipath==1.0
ajaxuploader==0.3.1
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
django-admin-bootstrapped==2.2.0
django-appconf==0.6
django-bootstrap-toolkit==2.15.0
django-compressor==1.3
django-image-cropping==0.7.1
django-mongodb-engine==0.5.2
django-tinymce==1.5.2
djangorestframework==2.3.8
djangotoolbox==1.6.2
easy-thumbnails==1.4
gunicorn==18.0
pymongo==2.8
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2013.8
requests==2.0.1
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

It's the damnedest thing and *any* ideas would be incredible. Thanks folks!